# TSQL Bulk Insert with Special Character as Delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, upload

I need the ability to `bulk insert` into an instance of SQL Server 2016 (13.0.4224.16 - `FORMAT` and `FIELDQUOTE` properties are not available) on special characters as the field delimiter and to also include any Unicode characters that may be in the data sets. I am trying to use `¿` (Hex 0xBF) or any character that I know isn't in my data set as a field delimiter.

I have a `UTF-8` encoded `test.txt` file containing some test data (headers excluded in dataset):

```
foo¿bar¿foobar¿
\n < last line
```

and a TSQL statement to insert:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[testTable]
FROM 'C:\Datasource\test.txt'
WITH (KEEPNULLS,
      MAXERRORS=0,
      FIELDTERMINATOR='0xBF');
```

into this table:

```
create table [dbo].[testTable](
    col1 nvarchar(50),
    col2 nvarchar(50),
    col3 nvarchar(50),
    col4 nvarchar(50)
)
```

when I run a `select` on my `testTable` it returns:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
foo┬    bar┬    foobar┬ NULL
```

Why are these `┬` characters showing up? I'm guessing it's my delimiters incorrectly encoded and included in the data? If I change my delimiters to `|` I can get the data in without issue but it exists in my data sets and would break the inserts further down the line. I tried adding `CODEPAGE=65001` which imports Unicode characters without issue using a pipe delimiter, but using the special character delimiter results in this error:

> Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.

Edit:
I've changed the import `txt` file to `UTF-16` encoding but still encounter the same issues.

Comment: Support for utf-8 was only added in SQL Server 2019, so that may be a first clue.

Comment: @HoneyBadger But has been available for years via `CODEPAGE=65001`, no?

Comment: "Versions prior to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) do not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding)." [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016). So looks like your version does, after all. In that case I don't know...

Comment: @HoneyBadger Fair enough, I've changed the `txt` file to `UTF-16` encoding. Same problem. Any idea now?

Comment: The unexpected end of file *might* be because you have a \n as row terminator, you could try `ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Shouldn't matter as `ROWTERMINATOR: The default is \n (newline character).` [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). But I tried explicitly including your suggestion with the same error occurring.